# Android resource linking failed when i deployment target

Tags: android, libgdx, manifest

I get this error when I select my android device. I'm using it for game testing with libgdx.

> Android resource linking failed
>
> C:\Users\oguzh\AndroidStudioProjects\Flying Smurfs\android\build\intermediates\Ä±nstant_run_merged_manÄ±fests\debug\processDebugManifest\instant-run\AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: attribute android:appCategory not found.
>
> error: failed processing manifest.

And here is my manifest xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.oguzhanaygun.flyingsmurfs" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:isGame="true"
    android:appCategory="game"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.oguzhanaygun.flyingsmurfs.AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The appCategory attribute was added in android 8.0, so if you're compiling with an earlier sdk, it won't work

Answer (score 1):

add `tools:targetApi="o"` to the `application` node and target an API level >= `26`

... or remove the `android:appCategory="game"`, when targetting an API level < `26`.