# error: attribute android:onProgressChanged not found. error: failed linking file resources

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I'm trying to handle `SeekBar`'s `onProgressChange` event. I've added `android:onProgressChanged="onSeekBarChanged"` to xml layout file  and function in my Activity kotlin file:

```
fun onSeekBarChanged(view: View) {
    Log.d(TAG, "on SeekBarChanged")
}
```

but compiler throwing following with error:

> Android resource linking failed
>   /home/radek/AndroidStudioProjects/TestMediaStore/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/stripped.dir/layout/activity_songfile_list.xml:37:
>   error: attribute android:onProgressChanged not found. error: failed
>   linking file resources.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
This is also applicable to other event attributes from different listeners like:

- `android:onLongClick`
- `android:onStartTrackingTouch`
- `android:onCheckedChanged`
- `android:onTextChanged`

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="com.example.testmediastore.MyViewModel"/>
    </data>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout    
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".SongFileListActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <include layout="@layout/songfile_list"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/seekbar_playback"
            android:progress="@{viewModel.playerProgress}"
            android:max="@{viewModel.playerProgressMax}"
            android:onProgressChanged="onSeekBarChanged"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"/>

    <fragment
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/play_control_height"
            android:name="com.example.testmediastore.PlayControlFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54449179/android-resource-linking-failed-when-i-deployment-target

Comment: @Masum My `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` is set to 28 in app/build.gradle. I even tried `minSdkVersion 28` but error still exist. BTW where I can find more info on minimum required sdk of attributes like `onProgressChanged`

Comment: Change your `minSdkVersion` and try it with 19.

Comment: @Masum I tried `minSdkVersion` 19, 18 and 28 with invalidating caches and restarting Anadroid Studio but it doesn't work.

Comment: Also see  this.


: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510219/what-is-the-difference-between-min-sdk-version-target-sdk-version-vs-compile-sd.

Comment: add your gradle in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was totally wrong: `android:onProgressChanged="onSeekBarChanged"`

Correct way is:

`android:onProgressChanged="@{viewModel::onSeekBarChanged}"`

```
fun onSeekBarChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    Log.d(TAG, "on SeekBarChanged")
}
```

OR

`android:onProgressChanged="@{() -> viewModel.onSeekBarChanged()}"`

```
fun onSeekBarChanged() {
    Log.d(TAG, "on SeekBarChanged")
}
```

The first solution is called **method references** ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#event_handling)). Signature of the method should be the same as signature of the corresponding listener's method. In my case it was `onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)` from `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener`

Second method is called [listener bindings](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#listener_bindings). And you can omit method's parameters. But pay attention to return value:

> If the event you are listening to returns a value whose type isn't
>   void, your expressions must return the same type of value as well. For
>   example, if you want to listen for the long click event, your
>   expression should return a boolean.

`onProgressChanged`'s return value is `void` (Kotlin `Unit`) so above is not applicable.